# Swift array types are now written with brackets around the element type with mutli dimension arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to define a multi dimension array of type SKSpriteNode (or any other type) with the following line:

```
var _tiles:SKSpriteNode[][]  = []
```

but I get the Swift warning: "array types are now written with brackets around the element type"

With single dimension arrays this can be done like this:

```
var _tiles:[SKSpriteNode]  = []
```

but how does it work with multi-dimensions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just double the brackets

```
var tiles: [[SKSpriteNode]] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

Along with using more brackets, you can also declare it without the syntactic sugar:

```
var _tiles = Array<Array<SKSpriteNode>>()
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that: “Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form is preferred, and is used throughout this guide when referring to the type of an array.” Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.”